# Should I use localisation tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently created the [uk](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk) tag, as I'm in the UK so wanted UK-relevent answers, as often the vegan or vegetarian situation is different in other countries, and if I'm looking for an alternative the options are often different in other countries.

For example my question [What's a vegetarian substitute for Parmesan?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/875/whats-a-vegetarian-substitute-for-parmesan) I don't really want to travel around the world to find some Parmesan!

Is this a good idea?

Comment: What a good question. I could think of arguments both ways...

Comment: Good question. An important thinking point here is that Stack Exchange questions are not meant to help only the person who asks them, but optimally, many future visitors. The underlying question then, is, how broad should the geographic scope of such questions be? Do we want a question per region, or answers for different regions under a single question?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you may use a localization tag, if you want to restrict answers to a locale.

If you use a localization tag, then an answer which is not applicable to that locale would be off-topic (e.g. an answer which started, "I don't know about the UK, but in the USA etc.").

A locale should preferably be a country, not smaller; or perhaps a common market (e.g. "europe" or "north-america").

The tag should only be used on topics that are locale-specific (e.g. regional cuisine, national culture, retail availability of food brands, etc), and not on topics which are not (e.g. don't tag all your questions with [uk](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk) just because you're in the UK).